# Terminal incrementing numbers in Unix

Tags: unix

Every command I type in unix the terminal is incrementing numbers for the commands.

```
Eg : 1> date
     2> ls..etc.
```

What is the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Check your `$PS1` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is offtopic, but to give you a short hint: the `PS1` (and some others) environment variable define the prompt of the shell.  E.g. `\#` gives the command number - just set it to something else (see bash man page, esp. section PROMPTING for details).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your terminal is configured to show the linenumber of the current command since being started. The "prompt" is also referred to as "PS1" and you can do all kinds of crazy stuff with it!

If you want to read up on how to this have a look here:

Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt

PS1 Generator & Preview: http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html

Collection of prompts (including pictures): http://jamiedubs.com/ps1-collection-customize-your-bash-prompt